# How to add an image and a label to UINavigationBar as a title?

Tags: ios, uiimage, uinavigationbar

For the moment I just know how to put a string as a title with:

```
[self setTitle:@"iOS CONTROL"];
```

or an image with

```
self.navigationItem.titleView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"icon.png"]];
```

but not both in the same time

there is a solution ? Thank you

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can create a `UIView` and add as many subviews as you like. For example:

```
UIView *titleView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 100.0, 40.0)];
titleView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"icon.png"]];

UILabel *titleLabel = [[UILabel alloc] init];
titleLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
titleLabel.textColor = [UIColor redColor];
titleLabel.text = @"My Title Label";
[titleLabel sizeToFit];

...

// Set the frames for imageView and titleLabel to whatever you need them to be

...

[titleView addSubview:imageView];
[titleView addSubview:titleLabel];

self.navigationItem.titleView = titleView;
```

Comment: thank you, it seems to work but the label text isn't displayed

Comment: @MaxPuis: I've updated my answer to set the textColor and size the UILabel appropriately.

Answer (score 1):

Create a new `UIView`, add `UIImage` and a `UILabel` as subviews to it the way you want and add that `UIView` using `self.navigationItem.titleView`.

Comment: whether I need to add it on each screen ?